# How to add disable field in ASP.NET dropdownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5

I need to add the diable field "Select..." in dropdownList. The data is bind along with datasourse in code behind. I am have tried to add disable field but I can see any result.

### Code Behind

```
AvailableRolesList = RoleDefinationRelay.GetAllRoles(null);
ddlRolesList.DataSource = AvailableRolesList;
ddlRolesList.DataTextField = "Title";
ddlRolesList.DataValueField = "RoleID";
ddlRolesList.DataBind();
```

### DropdownList

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlRolesList" runat="server">
   <asp:ListItem Text="SelectRole" Enabled="false" Selected="True">Select Role</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: What is a disable field?

Comment: What I interpret (from barely understandable description by OP) is OP wants to add *Select* as a default value to dropdownlist and perhaps also a ddl should be disabled if no valid item has been selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my answer

```
ddlRolesList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Role","NA"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add *Select* item after binding dropdownlist in code behind.

```
AvailableRolesList = RoleDefinationRelay.GetAllRoles(null);
ddlRolesList.DataSource = AvailableRolesList;
ddlRolesList.DataTextField = "Title";
ddlRolesList.DataValueField = "RoleID";
ddlRolesList.DataBind();

ddlRolesList.Items.Insert(0, "Select Role");
```